# Django for loop in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have two datasets:

```
ButikPages = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, Parent_id__isnull=True, IsActive=1, URL=shop_page_slug)
SubPages = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, Parent_id__isnull=False, URL=shop_page_slug)
```

In my Template I try to filter these two lists that if one ButikPages Query has SubPages it should a drop down menu if not a link menu.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    {% for page in ButikPages %}
    {% for parentpage in SubPages %}
    {% if page.IsActive == 1 and parentpage.Parent_id != page.ID %}
       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/{{ page.Slug }}/">{{ page.PageTitle }}</a></li>
       {% else %}
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ page.PageTitle }}</a>
       {% if parentpage.Parent_id == page.ID and parentpage.IsActive == 1 %}
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/{{ parentpage.Slug }}/">{{ parentpage.PageTitle }}</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

That works if a Menu just has one entry, but if I have two SubPages it appears two time, which is what I understand because the two for loops. But how can I access the SubPages without the second loop?

PS its easier if I just have one menu type I know it's working but the only difference is that I have two kind of menues.

regards.

Comment: Sorry I cannot test it now. But I found some mistakes about the position for loop of children. Maybe it works now.

Comment: I update a new solution. Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have built a tree-like object list in the model `ShopPages`.
I think you should create the tree-like structure in your view first, and then display it in the template later, instead of using two for-loop directly in the template.

Something like:

```
shop_pages = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, IsActive=1, URL=shop_page_slug)
parents = list(shop_pages.filter(Parent_id__isnull=True).values('pk', 'Parent_id'))
children = list(shop_pages.filter(Parent_id__in=parents).values('pk', 'Parent_id'))
pages = [
    {
        'pk': parent['pk'],
        'parent_id': parent['Parent_id'],
        'sub_pages': [
            {
                'pk': child['pk'],
                'parent_id': child['Parent_id'],
            } for child in children if child['Parent_id'] == parent['pk']
        ],
    } for parent in parents
]
```

And in your template, do something like:

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {{ page.pk }}
    ..
    ..
    {% for sub_page in page.sub_pages %}
        {{ sub_page.pk }}
        ..
        ..
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor}
```

Sorry I cannot test it now. But I found some mistakes about the position `for` loop of children. Maybe it works now.

---

I just suddenly figure out that you can use the reverse-FK to collect the children of your parent-pages. So if you doesn't change the `related_name` of the FK `Parent_id`, its reverse field would be `Parent_id_set`, then you can do:

```
shop_pages = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, IsActive=1, URL=shop_page_slug)
```

and

```
<ul>
  {% for page in shop_pages %}
  {{ page.pk }}
  ..
    {% for sub_page in page.Parent_id_set.all %}
    {{ sub_page.pk }}
    ..
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I like the idea, but my IDE says its couple of syntax errors. Misses multiple , and } can you confirm that your view statement should work?

Comment: Hi again :) Now I get: Field 'ID' expected a number but got {'pk': 1, 'Parent_id': None}. And thats why: children = list(shop_pages.filter(Parent_id__in=parents).values('pk', 'Parent_id'))
Parents have no Parent_id but child should read the value

Comment: I fixed it children = list(shop_pages.filter(Parent_id__in=shop_pages).values('pk', 'Parent_id')) but its not the solution for my problem because I need for my first if loop botch values: child and parents for decide which menue should be rendered

Comment: Did you try the second solution about using the reverse-FK? I think that one is much simpler than the first.

Comment: Yes it did not work, I dont know if this is the problem: Parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True) I know _set.all function just if the FK is in another model

Comment: Oh, the name of the field is called `Parent`. Then the reverse field name should be `Parent_set`.

Answer (score 0):

Move elements for `page` out of the nested loop:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
{% for page in ButikPages %}
    {% if page.IsActive == 1 %}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/{{ page.Slug }}/">{{ page.PageTitle }}</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for childpage in SubPages %}
            {% if childpage.Parent_id == page.ID %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/{{ childpage .Slug }}/">{{ childpage.PageTitle }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I don't really understand your `if` conditions, perhaps I modified them in wrong way.

Anyway, @林敬智 shows the right way for refactoring - pass data from the view already prepared for simple and stupid page generation. Avoid looping through all the SubPages over and over.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but now I can't check if a Parent has a child and can't render a non-dropdown for childless menus and a dropdown menue for parents with childs...

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found a solution, but I need a cleaner version:

views.py

```
def home(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    try:
        User = MasterData.objects.get(ShopURL=current_site)
        
        SubPages = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, Parent_id__isnull=False)
        parents_id_that_have_childs = ShopPages.objects.filter(Parent_id__isnull=False).values_list('Parent_id', flat=True)
        parents_tmp = ShopPages.objects.filter(ID__in=list(set(parents_id_that_have_childs))).values_list('Slug', flat=True)
        parents = ShopPages.objects.filter(ID__in=list(set(parents_id_that_have_childs)))
        not_parent = ShopPages.objects.filter(UserID_id=User, Parent_id__isnull=True, IsActive=1).exclude(Slug__in=parents_tmp)
```

Too much queries.

Template:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
              {% for page in not_parent %}
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ page.Slug }}">{{ page.PageTitle }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
              {% for parent in parents %}
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ parent.PageTitle }}</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% for parentpage in SubPages %}
                                    {% if parentpage.Parent_id == parent.ID and parentpage.IsActive == 1 %}
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/{{ parentpage.Slug }}/">{{ parentpage.PageTitle }}</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                    </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
```